Unable to Display QR Code Popup Window on Customized Windows Login Screen
I'm working on a project where I need to display a QR code on the Windows login screen using a custom credential provider by using ICredentialProviderCredential interface. The goal is to allow users to log in by scanning the QR code with a mobile app.
Problem Description:  I've made progress by creating a custom tile image on the Windows login screen, located under the sign-in options. Upon clicking this tile, a button is displayed to log in via QR code, and when clicked, it correctly triggers a "Button clicked" message. However, I'm facing difficulties with displaying the QR code popup window.
Here's a simplified version of my CommandLinkClicked function:
HRESULT CSampleCredential::CommandLinkClicked(DWORD dwFieldID)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (dwFieldID < ARRAYSIZE(_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors) && (CPFT_COMMAND_LINK == _rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[dwFieldID].cpft)) { 

        // Generate QR code
        const qrcodegen::QrCode qrCode = qrcodegen::QrCode::encodeText(dummyString,qrcodegen::QrCode::Ecc::LOW);
        saveQrCodeAsBmp("qr.bmp", qrCode);

        // Notify the external window to update the QR code
        HWND hwndOwner = nullptr;
        if (_pCredProvCredentialEvents) {
            _pCredProvCredentialEvents->OnCreatingWindow(&hwndOwner);
        }
        PostMessage(hwndOwner, WM_UPDATE_QR_CODE, 0, 0);
    }
    else {
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    return hr;
}

The issue lies in the fact that despite successfully executing the code to generate the QR code and trigger the message to update the QR code window, the popup window fails to appear when attempting to log in.
External Window Creation: (used for pop up window) To create the popup window displaying the QR code, I'm utilizing an external window with the following characteristics:
The window is created using WinMain function. It's a standard Windows window with specific dimensions and layout. It contains the QR code image and a button to close the window.
// External window creation in WinMain function:
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    // Code to create and display external window...
}

The QR code popup window is not appearing when I click the custom tile then button and attempt to log in. It only works when I try to pop up plain text.
I suspect there might be some restrictions or limitations related to UI interactions on the Windows login screen, but I'm not sure how to diagnose, debug or resolve this issue.
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Your new window must be served by different thread.
After your code leave CommandLinkClicked() method the window's message queue will not be served by Winlogon.
My suggestion is to create the thread inside of Advise() method and close/terminate it inside of UnAdvise() method.

not need create any threads here.  if you create own windows - create it in thread, to which main window belong
